# JS JQ How to reduce total value when click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I only know how to make total value using jQuery, but I don't know how to reduce the value.

Is there anyway to make total value be able to reduce price when click on image too?

I tried this but it doesn't work

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.items_img').click(function() {
    var path = $(this).attr('data-title');
    addImage(path, 500, 500, 0.5, -90, 3);
    var name = $(this).attr('data-name');
    totalname.push(name);

    if (totalname == '') {
      $('#name').val('');
    } else {
      $('#name').val(totalname);
    } else if ($(document).click(function(deleteObject())) { // I did this and it doesn't work
        $('#name').reduce('');
      }
      $('#name').val(totalname);


      var price = $(this).attr('data-target'); totalprice = totalprice + parseInt(price);

      if (totalprice == 0) {
        $('#cost').val('');
      } else {
        $('#cost').val(totalprice);
      }

    }
  })
});


function deleteObject() {
  canvas.getActiveObject().remove();
}
```

Comment: What did you try? Where did you have problems?

Comment: this `else if($(document).click(function(deleteObject())){ // I did this and it doesn't work
              $('#name').reduce('');
            }` is wrong what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Please click `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: Why is there an if when the function does not return a boolean or truthy/falsy object? `if($(document).click(function(deleteObject()))`

Comment: @brk trying to reduce totalname when I click on delete button but I don't know how.

Comment: @mplungjan yeah that's why i'm here, finding an answer

Comment: The problems here are that most of the code does not make sense and there is not enough details for me to make sense of it. I cannot guess what you are trying to do. For example you push to what seems to be an array and then test to see if the array is an empty string